# How can I use a Regex to get specific values from a text file delimitted by ,\n?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, substring

I have a SQL script as follows used to populate a db table with some data. 
I am then reading this file using StreamReader in C# in VS2010. What I want to know is, once I have this file read in as a string, how can I split each individual parameter into a substring?

So what ideally I want is to read each individual VALUE parameter into it's own separate substring so I can process this.

SQL SCRIPT:

...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[My_Table] ( \n My_ID, \n My_Title, \n My_Message \n ) VALUES ( \n 40, \n 'Hello, This is the message title', \n 'Hello, This is \n the message body' \n )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[My_Table] ( \n My_ID, \n My_Title, \n My_Message \n ) VALUES ( \n 41, \n 'Hello again, This is another message title', \n 'Hello again, This is \n another message body' \n )
```

I am currently debugging this and trying a couple of different approaches, one using String.Split() and the other using a Regex approach.

Here is my C# code:

```
// this is to find the VALUES parameters in the SQL file
private static readonly Regex matchValues = new Regex(@".*?VALUES.*?\((.*?)\)",
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
|RegexOptions.Singleline);

// fileText is the string object containing the raw text read in from the SQL file
public static string FindMatches(string fileText)
{
    List<Match> matches = matchValues.Matches(fileText).Cast<Match>().ToList();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
         string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
         string pattern = @"^,$";

         // do work

         string[] delimiters = new string[] { ",\n" };

         string[] splitGroup = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);

         string[] split = Regex.Split(value, pattern);

     }
}
```

So if I can briefly explain this code, the matchValues Regex is finding me the values for the insert parameters and this is working fine. (Note I've updated the SQL file with \n chars to show the layout of the file and how it is stored in the string variable when read in). Note that in the My_Message value there can be ',' and '\n' cases. However, the end of each parameter can be uniquely identified by ',\n' but I can't get this to work in a Regex and String.Split() can only use 1 char.

The List holds each case for each match discovered as I have over 50 entries in the SQL script, so I need to split out each individual ID, Title and Message from each Insert Statement into 3 separate variables that are nested within the loop.

Currently the splitGroup[] string object is returning too many substrings as we have new lines in the parameter values and the split[] string object using the Regex is just returning it all as one string.

I hope this updated info is helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why regex and not `string.Split()`?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, I've updated my question to be a bit more specific and explained why string.Split() isn't currently working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set RegexOptions to match data multiline, which means that regex will match dollar sign $ with end of line and not end of string. Here's the code:

```
string strRegex = @"^Regex Test";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"Regex Test for stackoverflow.";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also  use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.100%29):

```
var inserts = File.ReadLines(path)
         .Where(l => l.IndexOf("VALUES (") > -1)
         .Select(l => new
         {
             SQL = l,
             Params = l.Substring(l.IndexOf("VALUES (") + 8)
                       .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         });
foreach (var insert in inserts)
{
    String sql = insert.SQL;
    String[] parameter = insert.Params;
}
```